Comedy TV show in which there is a hair salon/barber shop named "In the Cut"?
The show had mostly Afro-Americans acting in it, and one of the guy's names was something like Delanze or Delance.  
In the particular episode that I watched, Delanze is going out with 2 girls at once, and while 2 guys are trying (sort of) to help him, 2 girs think that it is wrong, and try to get him busted. Alongside this, there is a girl who is being beaten up by her boyfriend, and calls 2 older women to help her out. They all refer to each other as "sisters", and these two women were involved in some sort of old clothes charity drive before they came to her rescue.
Hope this is sufficient to identify the series, because I could only catch the last 10 minutes or so

Any idea about when the show was from?

Tyler Perry's House of Payne features a black cast, a barbershop called In The Cut and one of the barbers is called Delante (played by Jason Dirden). The episode you're looking for is The Beat Down (episode 13 in season 3), that revolves around an abusive boyfriend, a clothing drive and Delante having 2 dates at once.

Perfect! Spot on! Thanks :)

No problem. :) Found the episode too. I'll add it in.

Even more perfect... Wish I could give another upvote just for finding the episode :)

This is a movie, but could it be Barbershop (2002) ? There was a spin-off series -> Here
It is a show with mostly African Americans and they run a barbershop.
From Wikipedia:

On a cold winter, Calvin Palmer, Jr. (Ice Cube) decides he has had
  enough of trying to keep open the barbershop his father handed down to
  him. He cannot borrow, revenues are falling, and he seems more
  interested in get-rich-quick schemes to bring in easy money. Without
  telling his employees, or the customers, he sells the barbershop to a
  greedy loan shark, Lester Wallace (Keith David), who lies about its
  future by announcing plans to turn it into a strip club.
After spending a day at work, and realizing just how vital the
  barbershop is to the surrounding community, Calvin rethinks his
  decision and tries to get the shop back - only to find out Wallace
  wants double the $20,000 he paid Calvin to return it, and before 7
  P.M. that day. Right after he admits to the employees that he sold the
  barber shop, and that it would be closing at the end of the day, the
  police arrive to arrest one of the barbers, named Ricky (Michael
  Ealy). He is accused of driving his pickup truck into a nearby market
  to steal an ATM, but it is revealed that the ATM thief, JD (Anthony
  Anderson), a cousin of Ricky's, was actually the one who committed the
  crime after borrowing Ricky's truck. Because this is, potentially,
  Ricky's 'third strike', he could be sentenced to life in prison.
  Calvin uses the $20,000, from Lester, to bail Ricky out of jail yet
  Ricky is angry as he believes Calvin betrayed him.
Calvin reveals that he found a gun in Ricky's locker in the barbershop
  and shows it to him. They stop the car and Ricky throws the gun into
  the river, proving that he does not want to get into any more trouble.
  Then they both go to see Lester. Lester, as well as JD and Billy
  (Lahmard Tate)(who were still trying to pry the ATM open and took it
  to Lester's place without his knowledge) are confronted by Calvin and
  Ricky. They demand Lester give the barbershop back. Lester is angered
  and orders his bodyguard Monk to pull out his gun. The police arrive
  just in time to save Calvin and Ricky but JD and Billy are arrested.
  Calvin and Ricky see the ATM, and get a $50,000 reward for returning
  it to police. They get the money, and the barbershop reopens with even
  better business than before. In the meantime, Calvin's wife, Jennifer
  (Jazsmin Lewis), has given birth to a baby boy.

